# What constitutes a good reading course in $p$-adic number theory?

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I have had a course in number theory where I studied Marcus and also a course in differential geometry. I have read Koblitz's introductory book on $p$-adic numbers. I am roughly interested in both $p$-adic numbers and elliptic curves. I would like to know what I can read so that I get a bird's eye view and a feel for things that happen in these two areas and also should go deep enough to know at least a few things in good depth.

I ***don't*** know any of these: algebraic geometry, representation theory.

What can I do with this modest background?
If you have had any student in a similar situation, I would like to know what suggestion you gave him/her. Thank you very much!

Comment: Knapp's *Elliptic Curves* does not presume algebraic geometry.

Comment: You could probably read Serre's $Local$ $Fields$. It's a bit terse but quite good.

Comment: For something at a considerably lower level than Serre, there’s Gouvêa’s book, but it might be pretty much like Koblitz. I like it a lot as a text.

Comment: I liked Svetlana Katok's  book p-adic numbers (don't remember the name) a lot. It has a good number of exercises. On the other hand, you might also want to take a look at Serre's A course in Arithmetic for p-adic numbers, it develops p-adic numbers as the projective limit of a projective system not discussed in Gouvea or Katok or at most of the places.    
For Elliptic curves, people usually refer Silverman's text but maybe that assumes the knowledge of Number fields and Galois theory. I can't say for sure as I haven't gone through this book myself.